# The layout is displayed incomplete when using thymelaf

Tags: html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a typical user panel with thymeleaf layouts.

As you can see on the expected result picture below, the layout is composed by a header and left menu. The contents chosen from the menu are displayed in the child section:

[image: EXPECTED RESULT]

However, the result I get is this one:

[image: ACTUAL RESULT]

This is my "fixed parts" code where the header is the "header" fragment and the menu is the "menu" fragment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Thymeleaf Layout</title>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="panel/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-cls-top " role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0" th:fragment="header">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">UserName</a>
        </div>
        <div style="color: white;
padding: 15px 50px 5px 50px;
float: right;
font-size: 16px;"> Last access : 30 May 2014 &nbsp; <a href="#"
                                                       class="btn btn-danger square-btn-adjust">Logout</a></div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation" th:fragment="menu">
        <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-university fa-2x"></i><label th:text="#{companyBasicData}" style="font-weight: normal"></label><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><label th:text="#{companies}" style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><label th:text="#{employees}" style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/billing"><i class="fa fa-balance-scale fa-2x"></i> <label th:text="#{billing}" style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money  fa-2x"></i><label th:text="#{payrolls}" style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<script src="panel/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="panel/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my "child" page where I import both, the header and the menu fragments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Thymeleaf Layout</title>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="panel/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>
<body onload="test()">
<div th:replace="fragments/panel :: header">
</div>
<div th:replace="fragments/panel :: menu">
</div>

<div>
    my page content
</div>


<script>
    function test() {
        alert("TEST");
    }
</script>
<script src="panel/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="panel/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find the gitHub repository with the sample code at this link:
https://github.com/MichaelKnight/thymeleafLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout sample is uploaded to my gitHub repository which you can find at the end of the issue description.

The top bar:

```
<div layout:fragment="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-cls-top " role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0" th:fragment="header">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">UserName</a>
        </div>
        <div style="color: white;
padding: 15px 50px 5px 50px;
float: right;
font-size: 16px;"> Last access : 30 May 2014 &nbsp; <a href="#"
                                                       class="btn btn-danger square-btn-adjust">Logout</a></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The side menu:

```
<div layout:fragment="sidebar">
    <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">

                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-university fa-2x"></i><label th:text="#{companyBasicData}"
                                                                             style="font-weight: normal"></label><span
                            class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><label th:text="#{companies}" style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><label th:text="#{employees}" style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/billing"><i class="fa fa-balance-scale fa-2x"></i> <label th:text="#{billing}"
                                                                                        style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money  fa-2x"></i><label th:text="#{payrolls}"
                                                                         style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Then you have to create the layout page:

```
<div layout:fragment="sidebar">
    <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">

                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-university fa-2x"></i><label th:text="#{companyBasicData}"
                                                                             style="font-weight: normal"></label><span
                            class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><label th:text="#{companies}" style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><label th:text="#{employees}" style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="/billing"><i class="fa fa-balance-scale fa-2x"></i> <label th:text="#{billing}"
                                                                                        style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-money  fa-2x"></i><label th:text="#{payrolls}"
                                                                         style="font-weight: normal"/></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Bootstrap Dashboard](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/)

This Bootstrap Dashboard example showcases how to achieve a three component page.

1. Top Navigation Bar
2. Sidebar Navigation Menu
3. Content Area

The Top Navigation bar is a root component inside your `<body>`.  The Sidebar and Content Area are `<div class="col-xs-*">` columns located inside a `<div class="row">` row which resides in a `<div class="container-fluid">` container.

Visit the link above and view-source to see the structure of the HTML.  Fundamentally this is a CSS problem, as your current GitHub project contains all of the elements, they are just positioned behind each other out of view.  Adding the appropriate Bootstrap classes will resolve the problem.

The Thymeleaf fragments are being included properly.

Comment: I will try with this approach today. However, I was expecting a similar solution to ASP.NET where you create the different parts of the dashboard and embed them into the layout.

Comment: @MichaelKnight You can still do that.  You just need to use the correct wrapping tags & classes so that the layout is properly structured.  By all means, you can continue to use Thymeleaf Fragments.

Comment: That's good to know I can do that. The point is, how to do it? I couldn't find any proper example in the thymeleaf documentation